# Aligning divs horizontally using CSS display:

Tags: inline, html, css

I am trying to align two divs horizontally. My list in the 2nd div is horizontally aligned, but the two divs fail to align horizontally as inline-blocks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the CSS and HTML code:

CSS

```
#wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
position:relative;
}
.navit {
position:relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display:inline;
}
.container-logo {
display:inline-block;
}
.container-user {
display:inline-block;
}
#user-nav-container ul li {
display:inline;
}
#user-nav-container ul li a {
background-color:#000000;
color:#FFF;
font-size:14px;
}
#user-nav-container ul {
list-style-type:none;
background-color:#000000;
}
```

HTML

```or-tag-here
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="top">
            <div id="navbar" class="navit">
                <div id="logo-container" class="container-logo"><a href="http://www.site.com/" id="logo">
    <h1>ServiceMyResume.com</h1>
                </a></div>

                <div id="user-nav-container" class="container-user">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="http//www.site.com">Site 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.site.com">Site 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TfzJ/

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you are trying to achieve? You want the all divs to be horizontally aligned?

Comment: Do you want to *replace* those divs horizontally and align them *vertically* on their common baseline?

Comment: I would like to horizontally align my logo-container and user-nav-container divs

Comment: Yes, what does "horizontally align" mean?

Comment: By horizontally aligned, I mean logo-container being to the left of user-nav-container(similar to float). I'm creating a navigation bar, and I would like the two divs to be inside of the navbar div, and vertically aligned at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of:

```
#user-nav-container ul li {
    display:inline;
}
```

This is what is causing your nav elements to be horizontal instead of vertical.

http://jsfiddle.net/8TfzJ/1/

**Update**

To vertiacaly align the two elements add `vertial-align` top to them, see: http://jsfiddle.net/8TfzJ/2/.

Note in the fiddle I've added a border so you can see the elements are vertially aligned. You may need to adjust margins and padding of the contained elements to fully achieve what you are looking for. Use Firebug for Firefox to help you here. You can inpect an experiment with the CSS in the borwser.

In a modern browser you should see: [image]

See this article for some inf on the drawbacks of `inline-block` and how to over come them:http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

On a side note, you shouldn't put block elements e.g. `h1` inside inline elements e.g. `a`. It should be the other way around. Try validating it here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: Jon, thanks for your post. I want those elements horizontal :)
But.... I would like to display the user-nav-container div and the logo-container horizontally, aka side by side.

Comment: See the fiddle I added to your question...the nav container and logo container **are** side-by-side

Comment: Jon, thanks for the prompt response. I checked the fiddle, but the result still isn't what I'm looking for. I would like the div with site 1 and site 2  to appear to the right of the "logo container" div. The result would be as if the logo was in the top left, and butted against the list, which would appear to the right of the logo. Instead, I see the "Site 1, Site 2 div" appearing below the link in the logo-container.

Comment: What browser and version are you using? I Get Log & Nav side by side in Chrome, Firefox & IE11. You will get issues with `inline-block` for IE7 and below.

Comment: Thanks Jon, it had to do with my browser window :P

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not as inline-blocks, but you you mean something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJfUD/)?

```
#navbar:after
{
    display: table;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
#logo-container,
#user-nav-container
{
    float: left;
}
```